# Rendering ReactDOM element with delay using setTimeout method doesn't work. How to render elements with delay?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, frontend

I've created tooltip plugin as React component. I have topology diagram with some nodes and I wanted to show this tooltip after hover on node. And it works fine but the problem is that I don't want this immediately, I want to do this with some seconds delay.

I've made method with rendering DOM element:

```
    showWithDelay(nodeContent): any {
    this.isVisible = true;
    ReactDOM.render(<IfsTooltip
        positionLeft={this.leftPosition}
        positionTop={this.topPosition}
        isVisible={this.isVisible}
        children={nodeContent}/>, document.getElementById('ifs-tooltip'));
}
```

Firstly I tried to delay only setting isVisible props to true but It didn't rerender compononent. So I decided to delay rendering this element but It also didn't help me.

This is how I'm calling setTimeout:

```
onNodeOver(system: any, element: any, hoverElement: TopologyElementType) {
    const nodeContent = (<NodeContent system={system} element={element}/>);
    this.leftPosition = element.x + 50;
    this.topPosition = element.y + 50;

    if (hoverElement === TopologyElementType.NODE) {
        setTimeout(this.showWithDelay(nodeContent), 4000);
    }
}
```

In constructor I have:

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.showWithDelay = this.showWithDelay.bind(this);
}
```

Does anyone has solution to solve this problem?

EDIT:

```
onNodeOut() {
    this.isVisible = false;
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('ifs-tooltip'));
}
```

Delay now works but when I move really fast on many nodes then I can see that content is overriding with data from every nodes that I mouseoverd. What I want to achive? When I'm out from node before tooltip is render I want to stop counting and I don't want to render this tooltip.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.showWithDelay(nodeContent), 4000);` (you were calling the function and using the result as parameter, instead of passing a function)

Comment: @ChrisG I've edited question because delaying caused some problems that I didn't think about before. Can You look at this?